# Objective C: Как передать данные между TableViewController и ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Ребят, подскажите как можно переслать массив из одного контроллера в другой.

Суть вот в чем:

у нас есть таблица с пользователями, при нажатии на стрелку должна открываться его страничка с данными
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.:Недостающие данные естественно добавлю в массив

P.S.S:Если кто-то еще и по поводу поиска данных объяснит(с помощью Search Bar), заранее скажу спасибо =))

Comment: Че т я не понял вопрос. Когда создаете `ViewController` там прямо и передайте: `newController.array = self.array;`